# Checking for a Tag upon entering an IsTrigger Collider

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I havent found any Way to check for an Tag or something similiar to differenciate various IsTrigger Colliders. For example, i have a Ladder with an IsTrigger in my Game that lets me climb it once i am inside the Collider. Now i want to have another Object with an IsTrigger(like an Item / a Pickup), but i couldnt find a Way to tell my Script that it should let me climb upon entering a Ladder-IsTrigger and let me gain Health upon entering an Item-IsTrigger (Right now its doing BOTH at the same time for both IsTriggers).
Some of my CharacterScript that i use for the Movement and Interaction with Objects:

```
void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D other)
{

    if (Input.GetKeyDown("w"))
    {
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().gravityScale = -0.2f;
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyUp("w"))
    {
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().gravityScale = 3;
    }


}

void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D other)
{
    GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().gravityScale = 3;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In "Trigger2D" or "Collision2D" functions, you can check whether `other.gameObject.tag == "someTag"`. Just be sure you've tagged the other game object with `someTag`.

Comment: Thank you, but i still have a  small Problem: void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D other.gameObject.tag == "ladder")

Comment: NVM, i have to compare the Tag in an seperate If-statement. Got it now thanks :)